# Python: TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment for MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, typeerror

**The entire code snippet which lead to the error is below:**

```
# Import sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#Selecting Numeric columns from the dataset
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
numericdf = data.select_dtypes(include=numerics)
# Initialize a scaler, then apply it to the features
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
numerical = numericdf
features_raw[numerical] = scaler.fit_transform(data[numerical])
```

MinMaxScaler in Python giving int TypeError code is above error is given below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-3ef670532e17> in <module>()
 27 scaler = MinMaxScaler()
 28 numerical = numericdf
---> 29 features_raw[numerical] = scaler.fit_transform(data[numerical])
 30 
 31 # Show an example of a record with scaling applied

TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Why the int TypeError? Can anybody help with the issue?

Comment: What is `MinMaxScaler`? Your class?

Comment: from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay folks Thanks for all who tried to help unearth the problem.

I did a few experimentation to the code and found that a for loop was able to enumerate what the single statement was not able to so posting the solution that works below:

```
for en in numerical:
    f[en] = scaler.fit_transform(data[en])
```

Answer (score 0):

features_raw is an integer, not a list, and thus it doesn't support item assignment.

Comment: How can i correct it? should I create a list and then assign to it?

Comment: first of all, post the code that lead to the error. Or is the code you have posted everything?

Comment: On your suggestion tried the list same error no difference:       **features_raw[numerical] = list(scaler.fit_transform(data[numerical]))**

Comment: 1. Where does "data" come from? I don't see where you define it.
2. Same with features_raw

Comment: data is a pd.DataFrame() object about 70 columns which have confidential data cannot share the structure.

Comment: So it isnt just a list? Did you overload [] (__setitem__) then? Also whats the type of features_raw?